# flutter/dart: How to create circular Text Field with one side border

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need the login screen with the shared images text field look so I am stock if anyone have idea so kindly share with me. thanks:
[image: login page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Container` and `InputDecoration`:

```
Container(
     clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
             color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
             blurRadius: 10,
             offset: Offset(1, -1),
          ),
        ],
     ),
     child: TextField(
         decoration: InputDecoration(
             fillColor: Colors.white,
             filled: true,
             disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                 borderSide: BorderSide(
                     color: Colors.blue, width: 4, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                 ),
                 enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.blue, width: 4, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                 ),
                 focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.blue, width: 4, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                 ),
                 errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 4, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                 ),
            ),
         ),
     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `TextField` with `DecoratedBox`.

```dart
DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextField(),
    );
```